# Nuxt: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am doing a [Nuxt tutorial](https://youtu.be/nteDXuqBfn0?t=2440) and I cant figure out why I keep getting this`Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` error. Is there something I am missing or could it be that Nuxt/Vue has been updated since the tutorial was released?

**Recipes page:**

```
 <template>
      <section class="recipes">
        <Recipe
          v-for="recipe in recipes"
          :key="recipe.id"
          :id="recipe.id"
          :thumbnail="recipe.thumbnail"
          :title="recipe.title"
          :description="recipe.description"
        />
      </section>
    </template>

    <script>
    import Recipe from '@/components/Recipe';

    export default {
      components: {
        Recipe
      },
      asyncData() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
              recipes: [
                {
                  id: 23,
                  title: "Gatsby",
                  description: "Eat Gatsby",
                  thumbnail: "http://www.eatout.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/gatsby.jpg"
                },
                {
                  id: 26,
                  title: "Rolly",
                  description: "Eat Rolly",
                  thumbnail: "http://www.prontomama.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Pronto-Mama-Recipe-Boerewors-Rolls.jpg"
                }
              ]
            })
          },1500)
        })
      }
    }
    </script>


    <style scoped>
    .recipes {
      display: flex;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }

    </style>
```

**Recipe details page**

```
<template>
  <section class="single-recipe">
    <h1>{{ recipe.title }}</h1>
    <div>
      <img :src="recipe.thumbnail" :alt="recipe.title">
    </div>
    <p>{{ recipe.description }}</p>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    asyncData(context) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve({
          recipe: [
            {
              id: 23,
              title: "Gatsby",
              description: "Eat Gatsby",
              thumbnail: "http://www.eatout.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/gatsby.jpg"
            },
            {
              id: 26,
              title: "Rolly",
              description: "Eat Rolly",
              thumbnail: "http://www.prontomama.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Pronto-Mama-Recipe-Boerewors-Rolls.jpg"
            }
          ].find(i => i.id === context.params.id) // to simulate single item selection
        })
      },1500)
    })
  }
}
</script>

<style>
.single-recipe {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nuxt: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948017/nuxt-cannot-read-property-title-of-undefined)

Comment: @Badgy thank you for spotting that. Had issues when I tried to post the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`context.params.id` is a string and the `id` in the array of objects is an integer therefore `find()` is not returning the expected object. Changing `id` to a string in the array of objects fixed the error.

Answer (score 3):

There no asyncData/fetch methods on components in nuxt. It is available only for page components. Reference  https://nuxtjs.org/api/

> asyncData is called every time before loading the component (only for
>   page components).

Comment: I can confirm this was the issue I had. I was trying to use asyncData in a component. There are now workarounds for this such as using fetch like I did below. Here is the reference: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching/#async-data-in-components

`async fetch() {
    const content = await import("~/data/components/CarouselFeatures/en.yaml");
    this.content = content.default;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was missing the .id in `context.params.id`

simple oversight.